# GKE Deployments are failing during a rollout to an unrelated deployment

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, autopilot, rolling-updates

Everytime I run a rollout for Deployment A, then Deployments D, F, and G are scaled down to 0 and forced to restart (and B is tied to C and E). From looking at the logs it seems to me that this is due to the fact that they share the same NEG, and when it attaches and detaches on A, then it triggers failures on D, F, and G. I have seen [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/1718), but do not know that it will help because these are deployments that are separate from the one being run. Is there maybe a way to have each of my services on their own NEG - or some other solution?

Or maybe that isn't it at all (maybe it is autopilot?), but it seems to always be the same groupings. Here are the events from one of the affected deployments:

> 58s  Normal   ScaleDown   pod/SERVICED-deploy-6bdc997488-kd8cz    deleting pod for node scale down

> 58s  Normal   Killing     pod/SERVICED-deploy-6bdc997488-kd8cz    Stopping container SERVICED

> 7s   Normal   LoadBalancerNegNotReady   pod/SERVICED-deploy-6bdc997488-b4gvd                                                      Waiting for pod to become healthy in at least one of the NEG(s): [k8s1-42e4f580-SERVICED-SERVICED-deploy-service-8000-4f86fa2f]

Comment: You may not specifically schedule replicas on nodes in different zones, which means they could all end up in the same zone (even same node). Try redeploying all of them in another zone and later change this to 'prefer' scheduling in different zones. (in the next Kubernetes release you try to enforce it using pod topology constraints).

Comment: Suppose you have at least 2 replicas and have in 3 zones,  a very low chance of the issues happening after the initial deployment. Once you can enforce scheduling in different zones, the issue cannot happen at all anymore after the initial deployment. **One suggestion is that when first deploy the LB, try to run the backends in all zones at first.**